# Exclude field when query with JPARepository

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I know that when marking a field with **@Transient** , that field will be excluded during persistence . But in my case , I just want to ignore it in the find() function , not with the save() function.

For example:

myJpaRepository.save(myModel) will save the model as usual

myJpaRepository.find(id) will query the object but ignore the field that I want.

Since I am working with Hibernate spatial, one of my attribute is  **com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point** , when perform something like myJpaRepository.find(id), it throws an exception like this :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For input string: "PO"; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PO"
```

I know exactly this is the error from the Hibernate spatial point for PostgreSQL but I can not find an exact solution to solve it , my work around is to ignore that field when query but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do you solve the problem? I have same problem.